# Angular Service using Factory, the data is correct but not showed at UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So far this is [the complete source](https://github.com/mudzakkir/angular-ui-router)

```
angular
.module('app')
.factory('Friends', ['$http',function($http){
    return {
        get: function(){
            return $http.get('api/friends.json')
              .then(function(response){
                alert(JSON.stringify( response.data));
                return response.data;
              });
        }
    };
}])
```

Controller:

```
angular.module("app")
.controller('homeCtrl',['$scope','Friends',
    function($scope, Friends){
            $scope.title = "Welcome";
            $scope.items=["2016","2015", "2014"];
            $scope.friends = Friends.get();
            $scope.save = function(){
                $http.post('/api/friends', friends);
            }

          }])

$stateProvider
        .state('home',{
          url:'/',
          templateUrl:'templates/home.html',
          controller: 'homeCtrl',
          resolve : {
            friends:['Friends', function(Friends){
            return Friends.get();
          }]
          }
        })
```

The result when I try to alert it:

[image]

The UI Blank:
[image]

*and my nav bar ddl is not working how to do the trick?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Friends.get() return a promise. You must use the then method :

```
Friends.get().then(function(data) { $scope.friends = data; }); //instead of  $scope.friends = Friends.get();
```

Comment: Thank You Sir.. I am still new at angular, and do not know what is promise. 
Can You give me clue with angular route to escape bootstrap dropdown url route?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your question. Can you reword your question ?

Comment: Try to run that app and go to the page.. The dropdown bootstrap using '#' and angular route using it to route the page.. It makes the dropdown bootstrap does not working...

Comment: ... You missing to includes bootstrap js file. Insert this two links into your head : 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

You use angular js, so I recomend to you to use https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ isntead of bootstrap directly.

Comment: Correct! Sir.. First time I got this thing not working, I assume the angular routing makes bootstrap dropdown does not working. But I was wrong.. Thank You for great suggestion..

Answer (score 1):

you should use $q for promises:

```
angular
.module('app')
.factory('Friends', ['$http', '$q' ,function($http, $q){
    var self = {};
    self.get = function() {

      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http.get('api/friends.json')
      .success(deferred.resolve)
      .error(deferred.reject)

      return deferred.promise;
    }

   return self
}])
```

Resolve:

```
 resolve : {
   friends:['Friends', function(Friends){
     return Friends.get();
   }]
 }
```